# Regex for allowing character, numbers and - in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a `textbox` where I want user to only input values like below example

**I-MH-NGPR-UBR-0001**

It means, a user can add only `numbers`, `alphabets` and `-`. Other than this it should not allow user to enter anything.

How to do this in javascript

Comment: Try `\w-` or `[a-zA-Z0-9-]` in your regex.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar - Can't use `\w`, because it matches on underscores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZ1mCQ/6)

```js
const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/m;
const str = `I-MH-NGPR-UBR-0001`;
if (str.match(regex))
  console.log("matched");
else
   console.log("not matched");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your HTML itself no need of javascript also.

```
<input type="text" name="myTextBox" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$" title="Please enter only alphabets numbers or -">
```